# jquery floating left bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replicate the following social bar that is off to the left:

[image: Floating social bar]

(the bar floats to the left and never scrolls off screen)

However, When I downloaded the source to that web page I noticed he was using he was using Sizzle.js. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this using jquery. Preferably without using a jQuery plugin.

I realize I could just use a fixed bar off to the left with CSS however I kind of want the feeling of it grabbing on to the top when I scroll past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name                = "#rightsidebar";
var menu_top_limit      = 241;
var menu_top_margin     = 20;
var menu_shift_duration = 500;
var menuYloc = null;
///////////////////////////////////

$(window).scroll(function() 
{ 
    // Calculate the top offset, adding a limit
    offset = menuYloc + $(document).scrollTop() + menu_top_margin;

    // Limit the offset to 241 pixels...
    // This keeps the menu out of our header area:
    if(offset < menu_top_limit)
        offset = menu_top_limit;

    // Give it the PX for pixels:
    offset += "px";

    // Animate:
    $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:menu_shift_duration,queue:false});
});
```

Actually this code is [already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225843/how-can-i-have-a-sliding-menu-div-that-doesnt-move-unless-the-page-is-scrolled-d/225935#225935) in SO

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jQuery for this. You can use simple HTML and CSS - using CSS3's property, `position:fixed`. See [this article](http://jacobonthenet.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/responsive-sticky-social-sidebar-tutorial.html) for more information.